# Ubuntu Server: Config ideas to safely power cycle?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I have an Rpi running Ubuntu Server 20.10 as Pi-Hole and Samba server at home. I try to conserve power as best as i can so at night or when not at home, i just shut off the Router/Modem by just flicking outlet power switch.

I assume this is safe for the ISP-managed router but for my Rpi, probably not. I observed it having trouble coming back up, although it works most of the time.

My question is, *can i take some configuration steps in terms of e.g. memory card write buffer settings etc. to make it reasonably safe to just powercycle it?*

Comment: If its a newer RPI (20.10 would indicate a 3 or 4?) , or if you're running n00bs - there's a USB boot option, either with or without the bootloader in the SD card that's going to be a lot more reliable. Even with my RPI1, overhead aside, it was rock solid when I usb booted it, but I wasn't so hot about needing a powered hub for it. Something else to consider is a read only filesystem.

Comment: Its a Pi 3B+, so i could indeed move to a USB stick. I have one plugged in currently anyway as SMB share. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SD cards suck as boot media, and in my experience with the original model B, was the main source of issues.

In addition to having more computing power as that old potato, the newer raspberry pi models have a few useful features.

Nearly every model but mine will boot off USB - it will need some special settings on 2 and 3, possibly with some permanant effects so [read through the docs carefully](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#usb-mass-storage-boot). Even on my Pi1, which would corrupt its storage if you as much as looked at it funny.... n00bs would let you install the filesystem to external storage. On a PI1, this involved fun like a powered USB hub that was both powering, and connected to a RPi.

If you're using this as a SMB share/Pi-Hole, you want lots of writable storage anyway, so simply booting off a USB stick is a good idea.

You can also, well, simply log in via ssh every night and gracefully shut it off. If I was feeling particularly lazy, this should be scriptable from another PC, or if you did this every night, set up a script to turn off the pi at a specific time before you turn it off at the socket. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out the best way to do the latter, but off the top of my head, systemd does have timers.

Comment: I see the consensus over "just boot via USB". Its a 3B+, so i guess i will do that. Thanks :) I am totally able to set up such a timed shutdown script, i am mainly looking for high-level ideas such as you gave. Maybe there is also background activities that Ubuntu server regularly performs, whose hard interruption would leave the storage in a bad state.